# Custom Event in Actions panel not showing Storybook-React

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a React component that emits custom DOM events when certain conditions are triggered. For example, I have an event lets say with name ‘onComponentSuccess’ that is emitted when the user clicks a button and a network request submitting some data responds succesfully. I have configured MSW for intercepting the network requests and everything works fine.

I have tried this, and I can actually see the event being logged in the console, but I don't know how to make it work so the event is shown in the Actions panel.

```js
export default {
    title: 'Example/Component',
    component: Component,
    argTypes: {
      handleOnComponentSuccess: { action: 'handleOnComponentSuccess' },
    },
    parameters: {
      msw: {
        handlers: [
         ...
        ],
      },
    },
  } as Meta<typeof Component>
  
  const Template: StoryFn<any> = args => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('onComponentSuccess', e => {
        args.handleOnComponentSuccess(e)
      })
    }, [])
  
    return <Component {...args} />
  }
  

  const args: ComponentProps & { handleOnComponentSuccess: (e) => void } = {
   
    handleOnComponentSuccess: e => console.log(e),
  }
  
  Default.args = args
```